# Named parameter with no default?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know I can create a named parametered python function such as

```
def t(a=None, b=None):
    return a+b
```

Then I can call with

```
 t(b=2, a=5)
```

However, if both `a` & `b` are not optional, then I need to check in the function in runtime, e.g.

```
def t(a=None, b=None):
    if a is not None and b is not None:
        return a+b
    else:
        raise Exception('Missing a or b')
```

Is it possible to check in compile time and fail as soon as possible?

e.g.

```
t(a=3) # raise error
```

Comment: Why are you using defaults at all then?

Answer (score 11):

Don't use defaults if the parameters are not optional.

You can still use those parameters as named parameters in the call; **all** parameters in a Python function are named:

```
def t(a, b):
    return a+b

t(a=3, b=4)
```

Note that passing in the wrong count of parameters is always a *runtime* check, not a compile time check. As a dynamic language, it is impossible to know at compile time what actual object `t` will be when you call it.

Answer (score 2):

> However, if both a & b are not optional, then I need to check in the function in runtime, e.g.

No you don't. Just don't provide defaults:

```
def t(a, b):
    return a + b
```

Trying to call it without the correct number arguments:

```
t()
```

Will lead to an error:

```
TypeError: t() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)
```

Or, trying to call it with incorrectly named arguments:

```
t(c=4)
```

Will also lead to an error:

```
TypeError: t() got an unexpected keyword argument 'c'
```